# why i am getting 404 on passing different function name in url?

Tags: php, restler

I don't know how restler behaves. when i am passing `getuser/2` it works fine, but when i am passing `/getalluser` it gives

```
{
error: {
code: 404,
message: "Not Found"
}
}
```

But when i changed the function name `getalluser` to `buyalluser` it works fine.

Can anybody tell me whats the problem with my function names in restler framework?

Comment: without knowing anything about restler... do you actually have a `getalluser` method in the underlying class? obviously you've got `getuser` and `buyalluser`.

Comment: yeah i have getalluser and it works fine.its just matter of function name.so changed it to buyalluser. && it works fine but i want to know that what was wrong in getalluser function name in restler.

Comment: Restler is using `get`, `post`, `put`, `delete` as method prefixes to automatically map them to respective HTTP method/verb

GET is the default HTTP method, so if you dont prefix a method with any of the above, it will be mapped to GET method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have already found out

Restler is using get, post, put, delete as method prefixes to automatically map them to respective HTTP method/verb GET is the default HTTP method, so if you dont prefix a method with any of the above, it will be mapped to GET method.